# in Lucene Spell Checker 5.3.1, how to get nearest match regardless of how bad it is?

Tags: java, lucene

I have some code that looks like this (fragment):

```
public List<String> search(String streetNumber, String streetDirection, String streetName) throws ParseException, IOException {

    IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(fsDirectory);
    Dictionary d = new LuceneDictionary(ir, "text");

    try(SpellChecker spellchecker = new SpellChecker(fsDirectory)) {
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        spellchecker.indexDictionary(d, indexWriterConfig, true);
        String text = streetNumber + " " + streetDirection + " " + streetName;
        String[] suggestions = spellchecker.suggestSimilar(text, MAX_MATCHES, 0.00001F);
        return Arrays.asList(suggestions);
    }
}
```

And I test it using this:

```
package ctc.api.web.service.impl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LuceneIndexServiceImplTest {

  @Test
  public void f() throws ParseException, IOException {

      LuceneIndexServiceImpl t = new LuceneIndexServiceImpl();

      String[] texts = { "123 n main st", "234 s apple st", "345 w orange st" };

      t.addToIndex(Arrays.asList(texts).stream());

      List<String> r;

      r = t.search("123", "n", "moin");
      org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(r.toString(), "[123 n main st]");

      r = t.search("234", "", "opple");
      org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(r.toString(), "[234 s apple st]");

      r = t.search("345", "", "oge ave");
      org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(r.toString(), "[345 w orange st]");

      r = t.search("", "", "geez");
      org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(r.toString(), "[345 w orange st]");

  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the last assertion to pass. Lucene returns empty because the match is just too poor (only the letters "ge" match). Unfortunately for my application, ANY match is better than NO match.

How can I force Lucene Spell Check to just return the closest string by editing distance?

Answer (score 1):

THe approach is called Fuzzy Search in lucene.Quote from the lucene [doc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches)

Fuzzy Searches

> Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or
>   Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, "~",
>   symbol at the end of a Single word Term. For example to search for a
>   term similar in spelling to "roam" use the fuzzy search:
>
> roam~ This search will find terms like foam and roams.
>
> Starting with Lucene 1.9 an additional (optional) parameter can
>   specify the required similarity. The value is between 0 and 1, with a
>   value closer to 1 only terms with a higher similarity will be matched.
>   For example:
>
> roam~0.8 The default that is used if the parameter is not given is
>   0.5.

There are many solutions provided for fuzzy search like [How to get Lucene Fuzzy Search result 's matching terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874278/how-to-get-lucene-fuzzy-search-result-s-matching-terms)

Comment: Nope. FuzzySearch is limited to an Editing Distance of 2.